# Chart.js not working offline with latest version (4.2.1)

Tags: php, html, chart.js, offline

I'm trying to display a chart from a MySQL database in offline mode using Chart.js. I have already installed the Chart.js library on my virtual machine (VM Oracle) running Ubuntu, which also hosts my server and MySQL database. However, when I try to use the latest version of Chart.js (4.2.1), I keep getting an error that the "Chart is not defined".

Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined http://localhost/affichage_graph.php:27

After trying various solutions such as using local file paths instead of CDN links and ensuring that my script is properly linked to the Chart.js file, I still couldn't get it to work.

However, I found a solution by downgrading to an older version of Chart.js (3.9.1), and now it works perfectly.

I'm curious as to why the latest version of Chart.js is not working for me in this particular case. Has anyone else faced a similar issue, and does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Here is my PHP/HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Graphique Poids</title>
    <script src="/chart.js-3.9.1/package/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

 


</head>
<body>

<div style = "width: 1500px;">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
    
    <?php
    
    
/*if (file_exists('chart.js-3.9.1/package/dist/chart.js')) {
  echo "le fichier existe";
} else {
  echo "le fichier n'existe pas";
}*/

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_esp32');
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_poids");

    foreach($query as $data)
    {
        $tps[]=$data['id'];
        $poids[] = $data['poids_value'];
    }


    
?>

    
<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const labels = <?php echo json_encode($tps) ?>;

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Poids',
      data: <?php echo json_encode($poids) ?>,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: 'red', // définir la couleur de la bordure de la ligne
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)' // définir la couleur de remplissage
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
      label: 'id',
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
  
  const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        backgroundColor: [
          "red"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```